# CSS - menu collapse in IE and Chrome

Tags: html, css

why does my menu collapse in IE 11 (do not know how it is with other ) and Chrome and not in Firefox?

[www.jonasfotograf.se](http://www.jonasfotograf.se)

Apologize that I did not leave enough information, here it comes:

```
<nav id="uBlogsy_nav" class="main-navigation">
<ul>
<li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
<li><a class="uBlogsy_nav_item"  href="/blogg">Blogg</a></li>
<li><a class="uBlogsy_nav_item" href="/livsstil">Livsstil</a></li>
And so on..
</ul>
```

css:

```
nav.main-navigation {
    float: right;
    margin: 15px 40px 10px 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
nav.main-navigation ul {
        display:inline-block;
        margin-right: 17px;
    }

    nav.main-navigation li {
        display: inline-block;
        list-style: none;


    }

        nav.main-navigation li a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 0.8em;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            display:inline-block;
            padding-right: 4%;
        }
```

Thanks,
Jonas

Comment: In order to make this question useful to others, you should add some code here and not only link to the page which might (and will) be different when a different user with a similar issue (or even someone that wants to answer this question) visits this question page.

Comment: also always specify the IE version you are referring to. i see the menu collapsing on IE9 for example.

Comment: Its working on my firefox 28

Comment: Sry for not giving enough information, I should have known better Trimantra: As I sad, it working in firefox but not in IE 11 and Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it work. I´m using padding-right: 5px insted of padding-right: 4%; So it didn´t have anyting to do with display: inline-block but it was padding-right in %. Can anyone explain that?

Answer (score 0):

that change should work in Chrome, worked in mine

```
nav.main-navigation li a {
  ...
  display: block;
  ...
}
```

but somehow it does not work in my IE 11

Comment: It works when I do as Maciej suggests, AND remove 

padding-right: 4%; from nav.main-navigation li a.

But I think it gets a little too tight between the menu items as it is now, but as soon as I put margin-right or padding-right the menu collapse.

Comment: I got it work. I´m using padding-right: 5px insted of padding-right: 4%; So it didn´t have anyting to do with display: inline-block but it was padding-right in %. Can anyone explain that?